# Lyric T5 does not respond to commands via Apple Homekit

Tags: smart-home, apple-homekit

I have a friend who has a [Lyric T5 Wi-Fi thermostat](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKJU2VC/A/honeywell-lyric-t5-wi-fi-thermostat) which he was controlling from his iPhone via Apple Homekit.  Recently, all commands from his phone stopped reaching his device, demonstrating that they were no longer connecting to each other. Why would this be happening and how could he fix it?

Comment: I think this question is too generic for the answer you have to be a good answer. Unless you can narrow down the cause of the problem, or the symptoms.

Comment: Hmm, beg to differ.  If you google "Lyric T5 commands not responding," you'll find that the answer he found happens to be at the top.  It may not be the only answer, but it appears to be the primary answer...  But it's up you.  Close it if you feel so inclined.

Comment: The problem is that based on the infromation you have provided, the problem could be **anything**. Your listed symptons: **not working**. A problem should be analyzed in more detail before asking on SE site. Also if Google gives you an answer then, google first and post after if it did not give you a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, turns out he found the solution [here](http://yourhome.honeywell.com/en/faqs/thermostat/wi-fi/lyric-t5-wi-fi/operation):

> If your commands are not responding, it means there is a disconnect between the app and Apple HomeKit. To resolve this use the following steps:
>
> - Go into Settings on your smartphone and select the Wi-Fi, then scroll down to see thermostat name with the last six digits of the MAC ID .
> - Turn Home Data off.
> - Uninstall and reinstall the Lyric app.
> - Go back into Settings and turn Home Data back on.
> - Make sure that your iOS version is up-to-date.

Apparently, doing this fixed his problem up entirely.

Comment: Did your friend give any insight as to what caused the problem?